# Redirect to folder only if root from other site referrer

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory, referrer, document-root

I have a redirect from root to subfolder. If user visits `https://example.com` it redirects to `https://example.com/subfolder`. But I want it not to redirect if referrer is my site, so user can reach root page.

For example:

1. User visits `https://example.com`
2. It redirects to `https://example.com/subfolder`
3. User visits `https://example.com/subfolder/file.html`
4. there's a link on this page to `https://example.com` and he follows it
5. It must open `https://example.com` and not to redirect

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ https://example.com/
```

Please, give me an advice to solve the problem, I'm poor on .htaccess rules.

Comment: That redirect match doesn't look like it would redirect to a subdirectory.

Comment: Is there actual content to show on the home page?   Why wouldn't you show the content all the time rather than just when clicking from the subdirectory's file?

Comment: Well, the aim is to redirect users who enter website to a subfolder that contains data in one language, but root folder contains data in other language. Forcing to navigate website in the specific language but user can reach pages in other...

Comment: I would not recommend handling language like that.  I recommend having each language in its own subdirectory.   The root URL can do language detection or redirect to a specific language, but it should never also have content.